# 2way SMS gateway using mobile phone

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

buying a two way SMS gateway is very costly. Setting up a mobile phone tool kit at SMS gateway works fine with low traffic but encounter lots of errors while high traffic is hitting your website. Instead, a one way SMS gateway is cheaper to send SMS to mobile but it cannot receive SMS from users back. I propose that sending SMS using a web SMS gateway and receiving back is though by Mobile phone as phone receive texts in sequential order and encounters low error rate. Is it possible to setup a mobile phone instead to receive SMS from users and to do necessary prefixed action?

Do this effect high bandwidth?

Can anyone explain me how to setup incoming SMS to ASP.NET SDK using a mobile phone not web SMS gateway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way to do this: one possible solution I have used in the past is writing custom code that will listen on a serial port. The phone is plugged into the serial port and sends a notification out every time a message is received. You write code that runs on the computer the phone is attached to that receives the message and then forwards the phone number and message body to the appropriate URL. In Java [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/) has the necessary code to do this for you: you'll need to buy a supported mobile device.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is it anyway possible to do this in remote server.

Comment: Sure. You'll need to set it up as a service, but I've used this in the past using the java service wrapper to run the process that connected to the phone and handled receiving incoming messages. This was on Windows Server 2008, and we used remote desktop to connect to it for management purposes.